# What is the distributional limit $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N e^{inx}$?

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, poisson-summation-formula

What is the distributional limit of
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N e^{inx} \; ?$$

If the summation is over $-N$ to $N$, the answer is $\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}2\pi \delta(x-2\pi m)$, but what about the above one?

Naive guess: If the sum is replaced by an integral, we know
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_0^N e^{ikx} dk = \frac{i}{x+i0}.$$
However, since $\sum_{n=0}^N e^{inx}$ should be $2\pi$-periodic, a plausible answer could be
$$\frac{i}{\sin x+ i0}.$$

Comment: I don’t see how you get the limit of the integral. The definite integral $$\int_0^N e^{ikx}dk=\frac{i\left(1-e^{iNx}\right)}{x}, $$ which does not converge as $N\to\infty.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As I mentioned the "distributional limit" at the first line, the context is clear. I am talking about the distributional limit.

Comment: By the geometric series formula, $$\sum_{n=0}^N e^{inx}=\frac{1-e^{i(N+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}}=e^{iNx/2}\frac{\sin((N+1)x/2)}{\sin(x/2)}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So what happens as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: I don't know. If it exists, the real part with likely be $$\frac{1}{2}+\pi\sum_{m}\delta(x-2\pi m).$$ But there is no guarantee there is a limit.

Comment: A fun question! One we should be able to answer! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{inx}$ is the (distributional) derivative of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}}{in}=s(x)+i\ell(x),\quad\ell(x)=\log\left|2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|,\quad \begin{cases}s(x)=(\pi-x)/2,&0<x<2\pi\\s(x+2\pi)=s(x),&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$ The derivative of $s(x)$ is $-1/2+\pi\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(x-2n\pi)$, and the derivative of $\ell(x)$ is what may be called "the principal value of $(1/2)\cot(x/2)$", analogous to [the case of $1/x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Distribution_theory).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your nice answer!

Comment: "On the money." :) Very good...